# How to pass multiple groupid & topic pairs to consume with node-rdkafka?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am using **node-rdkafka** for one of my application.
I want to consume messages from multiple topics with groupid.(groupid & topic pair)
But I am unable to find any details on **node-rdkafka** documention. So my question is, is it possible to pass multiple groupid & topic pairs to consume messages from many topics simultaneously from single kafka consumer connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A Kafka Consumer can only be part of a single group. This is the way consumer groups work.

However, within a group consumers can consume from multiple topics.

If you need to use multiple groups, you need to start multiple consumers and set a different `group.id` value for each of them.